# How to set model data in ActionFilterAttribute when using a typed view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use strongly typed views where all ViewModels inherit a class BaseViewModel.

In an ActionFilter that decorates all Controllers I want to use the Model.

Right now I can only access it like this:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ViewModelBase model = (ViewModelBase)filterContext.ActionParameters["viewModel"];
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
   }
```

The problem is, that I have to know the key "viewModel". The key is viewModel, because in my controller I used:

> return
>   View("MyView",
>   viewModel)

Is there a safer way to acces the Model?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OnActionExecuting works just before your Action is executed - thus the Model is set to null. You could access your ViewData (or ViewData.Model) in OnActionExecuted:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model as YourModel;

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This makes sense. Part of my filter can access values from route and need to be known before the Action executes. I still have this part in OnActionExecuting. The rest is now in OnActionExecuted.

Answer (score 4):

You can user this also in OnActionExecuting:

```
BaseModel model = filterContext.ActionParameters.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Value is BaseModel).Value as BaseModel;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but now I am able to access the model during OnActionExecuting:

```
var model = filterContext.ActionParameters["model"] as CustomerModel;
```