# Asp.Net MVC: Fill a model property from a ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm implementing a captcha control for lost password in a website, like described [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx)

But I feel very unconfortable with the             `

> filterContext.ActionParameters["captchaValid"] =
>   recaptchaResponse.IsValid;

Because:

- I've a strongly typed view, with validators
- The day I will change the property name without remembering this string field, it won't works.

So I searched how to edit an attribute of my model in the `ActionFilterAttribute`, in the `OnActionExecuting`, because my controller action will need this data. 
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965252/how-to-set-model-data-in-actionfilterattribute-when-using-a-typed-view), but can't works for me since I need the model to be set BEFORE the action execute.

So I thought that I could add a "Post variable", which will be read by the model binder, but it seems that the `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form` is in read only mode.

So how do you think I could put the result in my model?

E.g: `MyModel.IsCaptchaValid = recaptchaResponse.IsValid;`

Event if I can't avoid to specify the property field, it's better than now:

```
filterContext.Something.Else["ModelKey"] = recaptchaResponse.IsValid;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding an error to ModelState e.g.

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("", ""Captcha response invalid")
```

You can then check for ModelState.IsValid in your action (which you should be doing anyway)

Comment: Hum! This is very interessant! I didn't tough that I can directly modify the validation state! Great! Thank you! What I needed

Answer (score 0):

> The day I will change the property name without remembering this
>   string field, it won't works.

If you are worried about a property / string name change breaking the functionality, you could unit test your custom attribute.

```
public void CaptchaValidatorAttribute_SetsActionParameter_ForCaptchaValidity()
{
    // arrange
    var filterContext = new ActionExecutingContext
    {
        ActionParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        // ... other arrangements, like mocking HttpContextBase and HttpRequestBase
    };
    var actionFilter = new CaptchaValidatorAttribute();

    // act
    actionFilter.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("captchaValid"), 
        true);
}
```